# QT: Use stylesheet as external file

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I have a project developed in QT 5.9.5, so C++. I have an with a GUI and I want to describe the appereance of the widgets with an external global stylesheet.
I'm working with QTCreator. I added a general file named "stylesheet.qss" and QTCreator put it into "Other files" directory. I have not created resources files. Only the qss file inside the "Other files" directory.
To call the file, I write in the mainwindow.cpp (mainwindow is the user interface, mainwindow.ui) the following code:

```
QFile file(":/stylesheet.qss");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QTextStream in(&file);
QString text;
text = in.readAll();
file.close();
setStylesheet(text);
```

When I run the app, the application output give me the following problem:

```
QIODevice::read (QFile, ":/stylesheets.qss"): device not open
```

Instead, if I write:

```
QFile file("stylesheet.qss");
```

And also if I write:

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

the problem doesn't occur. However, in all the cases, the variable text is empty and I can't use stylesheet.
Checking the file.errorString(), it gives:

```
"Unknown error"
```

and checking the file.error(), it gives:

```
0
```

Someone can suggest me a solution or another way to add a stylesheet to my app?
Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add your `.qss` File in Resource(.qrc)
2. put this code that you want to add your `qss` in your program in `main.cpp` :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>

int  main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication  a(argc, argv);

    /**
     * Load the application style
     */
    QFile  styleFile(":/Style.qss");

    styleFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

    /**
     * Apply the loaded stylesheet
     */
    QString  style(styleFile.readAll());
    a.setStyleSheet(style);

    MainWindow  w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```